# Como limitar a quantia de endereços que um usuário pode ter no banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, servlet, controller

Eu tenho um banco de dados, e tenho a tabela usuário e a tabela endereço. Eu preciso validar de alguma forma para que um usuário possa ter no máximo 5 endereços no registro. Utilizo o banco de dados PostgreSQL e trata se uma aplicação com Servlet. Alguma sugestão de como eu poderia realizar esta validação no banco de dados ou na Servlet? Eu tentei fazer esta validação na aplicação:

public void cadastrar(Endereco endereco, Usuario usuario) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

```
    Connection con = FabricaConexao.getConexao(); //conexão com o banco de dados

    PreparedStatement comand = con.prepareStatement("select count(*) from Endereco where usuario_id=?");
    comand.setInt(1,1);

    ResultSet result = comand.executeQuery(); //result é o resultado do select certo?

    if (result>=5){  //entao aqui eu tento realizar: Se o resultado do select for menor que 5, entao eu vou cadastrar, porem esta dando erro aqui.
        PreparedStatement comando = con.prepareStatement("insert into endereco (cep,numero,bairro,rua,estado,cidade,complemento,usuario_id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        comando.setString(1,endereco.getCep());
        comando.setInt(2,endereco.getNumero());
        comando.setString(3,endereco.getBairro());
        comando.setString(4,endereco.getRua());
        comando.setString(5,endereco.getEstado());
        comando.setString(6,endereco.getCidade());
        comando.setString(7,endereco.getComplemento());
        comando.setInt(8,usuario.getId());

        comando.execute();
        con.close();
    }else{
    con.close();
}
}
```

porem não sei porque a linha onde: result <= 5 esta dando problema. O problema esta relacionado a propriedade eu acredito, mas eu não sei qual seria a propriedade correta que eu poderia utilizar para que o código funcione.

Comment: FK para a tabela de usuários + Trigger. Também podes fazer a validação em outras camadas da aplicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celina, o que voce pode fazer, é na sua aplicação, efetuar um select no banco de dados e pegar a quantidade de registros (endereços) e bloquear a inclusão de um novo endereço se ele for maior que 5.

```
select count(*) from TabelaEndereco where CodigoCliente='1'
```

assim voce vai ter a quantidade de endereços para o cliente com código 1

da uma olhada neste link

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/CountRecordsUsingPreparedStatement.htm

```
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
      if (rs.next()) {
        int numberOfRows = rs.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("numberOfRows= " + numberOfRows);
      }
```

Comment: coloca o if assim

if (result[0]>=5){

Comment: nao deu certo, ainda esta dando erro: array required, but ResultSet found.

Comment: deu certo aqui. Obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

public void cadastrar(Endereco endereco, Usuario usuario) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

```
    Connection con = FabricaConexao.getConexao(); //conexão com o banco de dados

    PreparedStatement comand = con.prepareStatement("select count(*) from Endereco where usuario_id=?");
    comand.setInt(1,1);

    ResultSet result= comand.executeQuery();

    if (result.next()) {
        int numberOfRows = result.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("numberOfRows= " + numberOfRows);

    if (numberOfRows<5){
        PreparedStatement comando = con.prepareStatement("insert into endereco (cep,numero,bairro,rua,estado,cidade,complemento,usuario_id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        comando.setString(1,endereco.getCep());
        comando.setInt(2,endereco.getNumero());
        comando.setString(3,endereco.getBairro());
        comando.setString(4,endereco.getRua());
        comando.setString(5,endereco.getEstado());
        comando.setString(6,endereco.getCidade());
        comando.setString(7,endereco.getComplemento());
        comando.setInt(8,usuario.getId());

        comando.execute();
        con.close();
    }
    }else {
        System.out.println("error: could not get the record counts");
    }
```

con.close();
    }